# How can I disable all lints in a file?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I have a file in my project that breaks many lint rules, and I cannot make major changes to it. How can I disable all lints within this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Dart 2.15, an inline ignore directive can be used to disable all lints in a file.

```dart
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
```

Case sensitivity and whitespace is ignored; the following styles also work, for example:

- `TYPE=LINT`
- `type = lint`

To learn more, the discussion leading up to this addition to the analyser can be found in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46957) and [code review thread](https://dart-review.googlesource.com/c/sdk/+/211460).